# Programatically create a docx and pdf file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There is this project am working on using flutter and i need to generate a .docx and .pdf file. I can't seem to find any helpful resource. Need help on how to go about this.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

Answer (score 2):

You should use [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) plugin to generate pdf documents. To generate an docs documents use [docx](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/docx_template).